# Prove if $g$ is an element of order $d$ and $d$ divides $n$ then $gn = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-groups

Prove if $g$ is an element of order $d$ and $d$ divides $n$, then $gn = 1$.

Comment: Hint: write up what it means for $d$ to divide $n$ (as in $n = \dots$) and put this into $g^n$.

Comment: No, not "exact", @MathGems. The OP's way of writing is very confusing but from what he tried in his *other* question he meant the other direction in his other question and he meant this direction in this question. An almost complete mental circus this have caused me...I'm dizzy.

Comment: @DonAntonio But the OP says in a comment to my answer to the prior question that the prior question is indeed precisely the same as above. It seems that he reposted it only to clarify the question (i.e. to remove the proof of the converse, to avoid the chance of misleading readers into thinking that he was asking about the converse - as happened in the prior question)

Comment: @MathGems, this is a mess. Let us leave the OP alone to untangle it as he's the one who organized it.

Comment: The OP has now clarified twice in the earlier question that it is the same question as this, so there can be no doubt that this is a duplicate of his prior question.

Answer (score 2):

$$d\mid n\implies n=xd\;,\;\;x\in\Bbb Z\implies g^n=(g^d)^x=\ldots$$